# Recommendation for Discrete Mathematics

Tags: reference-request

I'm taking a Mathematical Structures course as a 2nd year math major. Our course textbook is *Discrete mathematics and Its Applications, by Rosen*.

It's been very difficult finding good content on places like YouTube to make up for gaps in my lectures or to supplement my notes. I'm by no means asking for some quick 3 minute videos on problem solving, I'm not trying to neglect theory here. But I would greatly appreciate suggestions, whether it's an online course of bundled videos that costs a couple bucks or its a good youtube channel that covers everything I need to know.

This class is kind of kicking my butt at the moment, some recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I like this textbook. It is free online, and has problems online with solutions (and maybe hints): http://discrete.openmathbooks.org/dmoi3.html

Comment: Yes, Oscar's book is quite good and very nice at being *active*.

Comment: (Also, "Some exercises also allow you to enter and check your work, so you can try multiple times without spoiling the answer." so I think he has WeBWorK embedded, e.g. http://discrete.openmathbooks.org/dmoi3/sec_counting-combperm.html#TyW)

Comment: Personally, I teach from Rosen, and I find it to be a great, readable book (much more clear than other textbooks in the same area). Can I ask what about the Rosen text is not working for you?

Comment: Separately, Kimberly Brehm made video lectures following the Rosen text. I don't agree 100% with how she expresses things therein, but maybe 90%. A few of my students were happy to have this: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-gb0E4MII0L5lz8uQ8j5aSFQQHoAzXx

Comment: @DanielR.Collins It pains to read it, it feels very slow but overwhelming. I'm looking for something that is more engaging and doesn't draw me to sleep, tbh

Comment: @Lex_i: Quick, hopefully gentle advice. The single most important event in my math career was learning that I could sit down with a calculus book by myself and patiently read and learn from it (which how I learned everything and had a career thereafter). Be aware that everything later on will be slower, denser, and increasingly less likely to be in video form. The discipline is fundamentally a written one, and this class is introducing you to that path.

Comment: Also with Rosen in my class any given section tends to be first-half critical, second-half more advanced optional examples. See if you can read half of a section and then do the assigned exercises from that.

Answer (score 3):

Sue has linked to a great book (which I hope she turns into an answer), and here are two more quality ones that are free, at least, though less inquiry-oriented.

- [Doerr and Levasseur](http://faculty.uml.edu/klevasseur/ads2/), intended for computer engineers as well as CS
- [Keller and Trotter](https://appliedcombinatorics.org), a bit higher level but has some very good material

There are others at https://pretextbook.org/catalog.html but I am not as familiar with those.  Unfortunately I don't think that any of these (yet) has embedded videos, though I bet that will come.